# can't style elements in bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web, frontend

For the life of me, I can not get my html elements to style in one portion of my page. Using bootstrap and have some weird column stuff going on, not sure if that is causing the trouble. Please help me, this is driving me insane.

HTML:

```
 <div class="search-links">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-6 col-md-pull-2">
        <img src="media/Travis-Thielen-high-fiving-bear-in-bar.JPG" alt="Travis Thielen high fiving a bear in a San Francisco Bar" width="49%" />
        <img src="media/Travis-Thielen-at-great-wall-of-china.JPG" alt="Travis Thielen high fiving a bear in a San Francisco Bar" width="49%" />
        <h1>Travis Thielen</h1>
        <ul class="list-inline">
          <li><p>Contact</p></li>
          <li><p>Directions</p></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="job-info col-md-5 col-md-pull-5 col-md-offset-2">
        <p>test test test test ewst steesk test teest tesrt tesr isnt a test this is now a test</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.search-links ul {
margin-left: 2em;
```

}

just one example. I can't do anything with any of the elements, no border on the column div, nothing.

Comment: please make a fiddle

Comment: I added borders, [have a look here...](https://jsfiddle.net/r5tkjyay/) its working for me...

Comment: Have you tried !important

Comment: Its working for me too [check this](http://www.bootply.com/2sZGG4WQ4z)

Comment: I am flabbergasted. still not working for me. any idea what it could be? I am using sass as well, wouldn't think that would make a difference

Comment: did you try with pure css if it is working?

Comment: it seems to be working with pure css [here](https://jsfiddle.net/0pyttteu/)

Comment: Let me just say thanks for everyone putting so much effort in to helping me. I should clarify that I am using sass but am coding with scss and for the styling in this section am using only pure css. I am very confused how this can be happening, I've gone through all my html looking for an unclosed tag or something, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can override the Bootstrap styles.

```
.search-links ul {
margin-left: 2em !important;
}
```